# Microsoft Flow : Why is my condition to a column with Yes/No value is not working in if expression

Tags: microsoft-flow, if-condition, boolean-field, yes-no-field

Here is my expression which I want to incorporate in sending email action in flow:

```
if(PM/SH Approval Status=TRUE,"Attending","Not Attending")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(equals(variables('Input Boolean'),true),'Attending','Not attending')
```

replace **variables('Input Boolean')** with your variable.